# SQL count of distinct records against multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL SERVER "usage" that consists of 4 columns

```
userID, appid, licenseid, dateUsed
```

Now I need to query the table so that I can find how many users used an app under a license within a time frame.  Bearing in mind that even if user 1 used the app on say january 1st and 2nd they would only count as 1 in the result.  i.e unique users in the time frame.

so querying

```
where dateUsed > @from  AND dateUsed < @dateTo
```

what I would like to get back is a table of rows like

, appid, licenseid

Has anyone any ideas how?  I have been playing with count as  subquery and then trying to sum the results but no success yet.

Comment: Can you post the whole query you've done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested this and provides your desired result:

```
SELECT appid, licenseid, COUNT(DISTINCT userID)
FROM usage
WHERE dateUsed BETWEEN @from AND @dateTo
GROUP BY appid, licenseid
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT   appid, licenseid, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) as DistictUsers
FROM     yourTable
WHERE    dateUsed BETWEEN @from AND @dateTo
GROUP BY appid, licenseid
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy, paste and run to see if it works as you want it to:

```
SELECT appId, licenseId, COUNT(userId)
FROM usage
WHERE dateUsed > @from AND dateUsed < @dateTo
GROUP BY appId, licenseId
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted a query here but. I suggest you use PARTITION BY to produce a unique row count for each license id. You can create a sub query to the number of users using each separate license. The SELECT .... FROM this sub query and use a HAVING clause to filter on your preferred dates/users. Perhaps not the best explanation. 
Please post an example query.